How to lock table row with SQLAlchemy ORM after commit?
I am working with SQLalchemy orm. I add a register using session.add(object) and then I commit it with session.commit().
After commit I continue working on the orm object so I need to lock it so other processes can't edit the object. I need the same behaviour as session.query.with_for_update. Is there a way to do it?
import MyOrm
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


engine = create_engine(url=f'postgresql://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

data = {"name":"John", "number":1, "request":"registered"}

with session_factory() as session:
    try:
        object = MyORm(**data)
        session.add(object)
        # persist in db as data has been registered
        session.commit() 
        # this function process the data and do some things
        process_data(object) 
        # after the function, change request value
        object.request = "processed"
        # save the changes
        session.commit()
    except Exception:
        session.rollback()
print("completed")


It is between two session.commit() when I want to lock the register so it won't be modified by other process

Do you need to commit twice? Would it be sufficient to replace the first commit with session.flush()?

session.flush() does not persist in DB and if there is an exception in process_data(object) and rollback() is performed, I need the register in DB. With flush(), in rollback, the register in not saved in db

Perhaps this would do what you want (I've never used it).  The object needs to be refreshed after the first commit.

I just tested the suggestion from @snakecharmerb and it worked for me. Immediately after the first .commit() do session.refresh(object, with_for_update=True)

thanks a lot session.refresh(object, with_for_update=True) works perfectly

The Session.refresh method accepts a boolean argument, with_for_update.

optional boolean True indicating FOR UPDATE should be used, or may be a dictionary containing flags to indicate a more specific set of FOR UPDATE flags for the SELECT; flags should match the parameters of Query.with_for_update().

Here is a snippet that demonstrates its use, and the log output:
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column


class Base(orm.DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__= 't78646723'

    id:Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str | None]


engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with orm.Session(engine) as s:
    mm = MyModel()
    s.add(mm)
    s.commit()

    s.refresh(mm, with_for_update=True)
    mm.name = 'A'
    s.commit()

Log output:
<snip/>
2024-06-22 14:01:07,288 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE t78646723 (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2024-06-22 14:01:07,288 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00014s] {}
2024-06-22 14:01:07,301 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2024-06-22 14:01:07,302 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-06-22 14:01:07,303 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO t78646723 (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING t78646723.id
2024-06-22 14:01:07,303 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00014s] {'name': None}
2024-06-22 14:01:07,304 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2024-06-22 14:01:07,306 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-06-22 14:01:07,308 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT t78646723.id, t78646723.name 
FROM t78646723 
WHERE t78646723.id = %(pk_1)s FOR UPDATE
2024-06-22 14:01:07,308 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00016s] {'pk_1': 1}
2024-06-22 14:01:07,310 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE t78646723 SET name=%(name)s WHERE t78646723.id = %(t78646723_id)s
2024-06-22 14:01:07,310 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00022s] {'name': 'A', 't78646723_id': 1}
2024-06-22 14:01:07,311 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT


It seems that between the calls to commit() and refresh() there is a short window where the object is not locked

@sshilovsky True, but I don't see how it can be avoided, if, as the OP states, they need to commit after adding to the session. Perhaps, depending on the isolation level, they could use a savepoint within a single transaction, so that the new record is invisible to other transactions, avoiding the need for locking, but that is conjecture.
